# Set dataframe column type to character instead of factor (default) R

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

```
dataf <- data.frame(Alert=logical(),IQR=integer(),Kurtosis=integer(),Entropy=integer(),Skewness=integer(),Sex=character(),Complex=character(),Picos=integer(),PicosFil=integer(),Umbral=integer(),Gama=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dataf <- rbind(dataf,list(Alert=FALSE,IQR=2.6938,Kurtosis=1.73447,Entropy=1.76160,Skewness=0.140613,Sex="Mujer",Complex="Slim",Picos=0,PicosFill=0,Umbral=15.708,Gama="Alta"))
dataf <- rbind(dataf,list(Alert=FALSE,IQR=0.179574,Kurtosis=19.0538,Entropy=0.74779,Skewness=1.1355,Sex="Mujer",Complex="Slim",Picos=1,PicosFill=1,Umbral=18.975,Gama="Media"))
```

I have a problem with `Gama`, when I put in a new value (string), I get the following error:

> Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Media") :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Why are you creating the data frame this way?  The first line is irrelevant.  You can just use `data.frame` instead of `list` on the second line and begin there.

Comment: Because all the values change every moment, i have an app where i get that values in android studio, and i only copy paste the lines for get a decisions tree, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your lists.
You can see when you add the first line, all the `character` columns on your df turn into `factor`

```
dataf <- data.frame(Alert=logical(),IQR=integer(),Kurtosis=integer(),Entropy=integer(),Skewness=integer(),Sex=character(),Complex=character(),Picos=integer(),PicosFil=integer(),Umbral=integer(),Gama=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dataf <- rbind(dataf,list(Alert=FALSE,IQR=2.6938,Kurtosis=1.73447,Entropy=1.76160,Skewness=0.140613,Sex="Mujer",Complex="Slim",Picos=0,PicosFill=0,Umbral=15.708,Gama="Alta"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dataf <- rbind(dataf,list(Alert=FALSE,IQR=0.179574,Kurtosis=19.0538,Entropy=0.74779,Skewness=1.1355,Sex="Mujer",Complex="Slim",Picos=1,PicosFill=1,Umbral=18.975,Gama="Media"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call` to do this.

```
lst <- list(
    list(Alert=FALSE,IQR=2.6938,Kurtosis=1.73447,Entropy=1.76160,Skewness=0.140613,Sex="Mujer",Complex="Slim",Picos=0,PicosFill=0,Umbral=15.708,Gama="Alta"),
    list(Alert=FALSE,IQR=0.179574,Kurtosis=19.0538,Entropy=0.74779,Skewness=1.1355,Sex="Mujer",Complex="Slim",Picos=1,PicosFill=1,Umbral=18.975,Gama="Media")
)
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst)
```

Note that `do.call(rbind, lst)` will return a `matrix`, you need to explicitly call the `data.frame` method.